# Term "Eye load"?

Tags: terminology

I am missing a term to describe the mental load which is needed for a human to parse a large menu.

For example I want to switch to google forms:

[image: eye-load--automcomplete-vs-searching-with-eyes]

My eyes need to parse the symbols and/or text to find the right place to click.

I would call it "eye load" but I think this term does not exist.

If you compare this to an autocomplete solution, where a user can enter a text, then an autocomplete solution needs much less "eye load".

The term I am searching should be a sub-type of "cognitive load". That's why "eye load" came to my mind.

Is there a common UX term for this?

Comment: Informally (in situations where humor would be OK), I've heard it called an "eye chart".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact UX term, but your question is directly related to [eyetracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_tracking). *(Wikipedia)*

> Eye tracking is the process of measuring either the point of gaze (where one is looking) or the motion of an eye relative to the head.

While it is not exactly about measurement, there are several possible terms to highlight in the description.

### Eye fixation

**Eye fixation** or **visual fixation** is the maintaining of the visual gaze on a single location. Humans (and other animals with a fovea) typically alternate saccades and visual fixations, the notable exception being in smooth pursuit, controlled by a different neural substrate that appear to have developed for hunting prey.

> ...an autocomplete solution needs much less "**eye fixation**".

Answer (score 3):

I still think "cognitive load" is the most effective and is something that most people can understand when you reference that the visuals or visual stimuli is creating a large cognitive load. I have also heard "eye chart" as another user cited, but I don't think it's as effective in communicating that you are calling out a negative. Cognitive load caused by something visual still causes us emotional or physical responses - not being able to make a decision fast enough can slow our bodies down (and create hormonal responses like fight or flight & cortisol increases).

Otherwise, I would refer to [Laws of UX](https://lawsofux.com) to help you out:
Law of Similarity, or Hicks Law could help you explain the phenomenon to others. Advocating for designing around Law of Pragnaz would help you communicate how to prevent that cognitive load.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your definition of "Law of Pragnaz"? I found too many links, but none looked authoritative.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to [Hick's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law)

Comment: I 'd call it cognitive load as well.   The processing of the information takes place in the brain not in the eye.

Comment: @guettli Did you find this one too? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_pragnanz

Comment: @jazZRo strange, that this did not pop up in my search results. It looks it is not so much about cognitive load, more about beauty (or symmetry).

Comment: @guettli link : lawsofux.com - also yes it is about beauty and symmetry but also what impact that has on cognition.

Comment: @KrooshalSolutions in this current context I have an opinion. I don't want to see beautiful things. I can type fast. I want to type and I want to filter the results to a very short list.

Comment: @guettli "beautiful things" can be as simple as making sure that text has proper padding and contrast - just to keep in mind. also so many elements = negative impact to cognition. I think the Law of UX page demonstrates that better than the wiki.

Comment: @KrooshalSolutions There are different kinds of UXs. I use the command line since more than 25 years and I like it. I like the chrome address bar and PyCharm, too. All these tools have a great command line (autocomplete). Is this covered by the Law of UX page?

Comment: Perceptual Grouping IS cognitive load: its your brain using existing memorised patterns to sort the incoming data.  If the data is arranged in a way that the pattern will not sort ( ie "not beautiful" ) then the brain has to work harder, and may fail to totally resolve the data into images (which is how visual illusions work).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the term to have a clear relationship or association with the concept of congnitive load, then perhaps 'visual cognitive load' is something you might consider?

Or if you want the category of cognitive load to be more specific about visual perception and/or visual processing then you can put those additional labels and perhaps come up with an interesting acronym :)

I don't think cognitive load is always well defined and classified because we are generally interested in the net effect or outcome of this. Whether it is a menu that has lots of icons or providing suggested terms in a search input, usually the end result we want to achieve is for the user to complete a task with more efficiency and less error. And since design principles apply a balance or combination of different techniques I guess there isn't always a need to be so specific about a particular type of cognitive load.